# If-else not executing in powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am currently trying to create a PowerShell script that performs the same functionality as `cd`, but also checks for a .git folder (new directory is a git repository) and then if true subsequently fetches and performs `git status`.

I am trying to debug at the moment in PowerShell ISE, but in the debugger my script skips straight over the blocks inside of the `if..else` statements. Is this a syntax error, or should the `if..else` work correctly?

```
function gd {
    #set parameters taken from program (only file location)
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [String]$location
    )

    #get current directory location
    [String]$Cl = $(Get-Location)

    Set-Location $location

    [String]$Nl = $(Get-Location)

    if ($Cl -eq $Nl) {
        return
    } else {
        Get-ChildItem -Hidden | Where-Object {
            $_.Name -eq ".git"
        } | Write-Output "Eureka!";
        git fetch;
        git status;
        return
        Write-Output "No .git found here!"
    }
}
```

P.S: I am aware that the long `Where-Object` pipe is awful (and indubitably non-functional as-is), but this is my 1st script. Would welcome any help with it but my main issue is the execution skipping the if/else code blocks.

Comment: Why not making `$location` mandatory or defaulting to current location and checking `if (Test-Path (Join-Path $location ".git"))` ?

Comment: I did want to make $location mandatory but don't know how to enter multiple param constraints at once. However Test-path is a good idea, I'll give that a go.

Comment: Your test-path is better semantics in the script, but I still can't my if statements to execute properly unfortunately

Comment: Do you want to run `git fetch` and `git status` only when you cd into the root of a git tree? Or for subfolders as well?

Comment: Addendum: judging from your initial code formatting you seem to be under the impression that `git fetch` and `git status` were part of the pipeline and would only run if `Where-Object` found a match. That is not the case. Both commands will be run every time `$Cl` and `$Nl` are not the same.

Comment: Ansgar -> only wanted to run it for the root of git directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have an error in your Where-Object pipe which should have been an another if block. See my modified code and it works for me.

```
function gd {
    #set parameters taken from program (only file location)
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [String]$location
    )
    #get current directory location
    [String]$Cl = $(Get-Location)

    Set-Location $location
    $location
    [String]$Nl = $(Get-Location)

    if ($Cl -eq $Nl) {
    return
    } else {
        if(Get-ChildItem -Hidden | Where-Object {
            $_.Name -eq ".git"
        } ) 
    {
        Write-Output "Eureka!"
        git fetch;
        git status;
        }
        else{
        Write-Output "No .git found here!"
    }
    }
}
gd D:\<git-folder>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou I'll give this a try on the Powershell ISE, possibly the incorrect pipe is stopping it from taking the expected execution path

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Test-Path` to check for a `.git` subfolder. I'd also recommend checking if the repository actually was cloned before calling `git fetch`.

```
function Set-LocationGit {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Location
    )

    if ($Location -eq $PWD.Path) {
        return  # path not changed => nothing to do
    }

    Set-Location $Location

    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath '.\.git' -Type Container) {
        if (git config --get 'remote.origin.url') { git fetch }
        git status
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution, but not sure I understand all of it such as the flags on Test-Path. Only really wanted to make a simple script but I am sure this solution is likely more efficient/accurate. One thing I am curious about is how do you know that git config --get returns a boolean value?

Comment: `git config --get` does not return a boolean value. But PowerShell [doesn't need it to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) in the first place. The parameters for `Test-Path` are explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-3.0) as well as the cmdlet help (`Get-Help Test-Path`).